# Yii2 Logout admin part doesnt work correct

Tags: php, authentication, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I used Yii2 advanced. Everyhting is working well but only logout in my admin panel do not working correctly. When i click Logout, it is render me to index.php and do not log me out, second click ot log out it render me to login.php , but when i try to connect to admin part, actually i am still logged ... and if i wait 15-20 sek it log me out and rend me to login.php... i really dont understant wants going on ... 
Here is my action:

```
<li class="dropdown menu-merge">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle fw600 p15" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <span class="hidden-xs pl15"><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Hi'); ?>, <?php echo Yii::$app->user->identity->username; ?></span>
     <span class="caret caret-tp hidden-xs"></span>
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu list-group dropdown-persist w250" role="menu">
     <li class="dropdown-footer">
        <a href="/admin/user/settings/profile" class="">
           <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></span>  <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Profile'); ?> </a>
     </li>
     <li class="dropdown-footer">
       <a>
          <?php
          echo Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
               . Html::submitButton(
               '<span class="fa fa-power-off pr5"></span>' . Yii::t('app', 'Logout'), ['class' => 'btn-link']
               )                    
               . Html::endForm() 
          ?>
          </a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

here is the action

```
  public function actionLogout() {
            Yii::$app->user->logout();

            return $this->goHome();
        }
```

settings in my behaviors action:

```
public function behaviors() {
        if (Yii::$app->user->identity) {
            return [
                'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'ruleConfig' => [
                        'class' => AccessRule::className(),
                    ],
                    'rules' => [
                        [
                            'allow' => true,
                            'roles' => ['SuperAdmin', 'Admin'],
                        ],
                        [
                            'actions' => ['selectaddress', 'addproductreview', 'clearallspecs', 'addincomparelist', 'makeexpressorder', 'buyproductwithqty', 'loadcolorgallery', 'drawgraph', 'addproductcomment',
                                'addfornewsletter', 'setspecval', 'addrating', 'deletefromwishlist', 'deletefromcomparelist', 'tbi', 'buyproduct', 'deleteproductfromcart', 'deleteallproducts',
                                'changeqtyfromcartup', 'changeqtyfromcartdown', 'addinwishlist'],
                            'allow' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                    'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                return $this->redirect('/bg/user/logout');
            },
                ],
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'logout' => ['post'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'ruleConfig' => [
                        'class' => AccessRule::className(),
                    ],
                    'rules' => [
                        [
                            'allow' => true,
                            'roles' => ['SuperAdmin', 'Admin'],
                        ],
                        [
                            'actions' => ['selectaddress', 'addproductreview', 'clearallspecs', 'addincomparelist', 'makeexpressorder', 'buyproductwithqty', 'loadcolorgallery', 'drawgraph', 'addproductcomment',
                                'addfornewsletter', 'setspecval', 'addrating', 'deletefromwishlist', 'deletefromcomparelist', 'tbi', 'buyproduct', 'deleteproductfromcart', 'deleteallproducts',
                                'changeqtyfromcartup', 'changeqtyfromcartdown', 'addinwishlist'],
                            'allow' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'logout' => ['post'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to use `GET` instead of `POST` when click on logout button

Comment: when i tried - error method not allowed ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this array in `rules`

```
[
    'allow' => true,
    'action'=>['logout','index'],
    'roles' => ['@'],
],
```

and use this for logout

```
Html::a(
   'Sign out', ['/site/logout'], ['data-method' => 'post', 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-flat']
)
```